# Pytorch: How to transform image patches into matrix of feature vectors?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, patch

For use as input in a neural network, I want to obtain a matrix of feature vectors from image patches. I'm using the Fashion-MNIST dataset (28x28 images) and have used Tensor.unfold to obtain patches (16 7x7 patches) by doing:

```
#example on one image
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
        root="../data", train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), download=True)
x = mnist_train[0][0][-1, :, :]
x = x.unfold(0, 7, 7).unfold(1, 7, 7)
x.shape
>>> torch.Size([4, 4, 7, 7])
```

Here I end up with a 4x4 tensor of 7x7 patches, however I want to vectorize each patch to obtain a matrix ***X*** with dimensions (16: number of patches x d: dimensions of feature vector). I'm unsure whether flatten() can be used here and how I would go about using it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you can get from 4x4 x 7x7 to 16x7x7 with `x.view(-1,7,7)`. Just verify the patches are unfolded on the correct dimension

Comment: Thanks for the reply, running `x.view(-1,7,7)`, gives me the following error: RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead. However using `reshape` instead of `view` gives me the desired format before vectorizing (`>>> torch.Size([16, 7, 7])` - thank you, it should be fairly simple to flatten from here. (I'll update with an answer once finished)

Comment: Ah yes, the explanation for this is: -> unfold is a tensor view operation which means that the output is not a contiguous tensor (rather an intelligently crafted pointer to two or more contiguous tensors). View is also a tensor view op which returns a non-contiguous view of a tensor. Tensor view ops require contiguous tensor inputs. Every operation except for `view` checks for this error and automatically reallocates a new contiguous tensor with the same elements if needed. `view` is the only operation that doesn't automatically make a new contiguous tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this out, moving the content of the comments to here:

```
#example on one image
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="../data", train=True, 
transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), download=True)
x = mnist_train[0][0][-1, :, :]
x = x.unfold(0, 7, 7).unfold(1, 7, 7)
x.shape
```

Output:

```
>>> torch.Size([4, 4, 7, 7])
```

And then:

```
x.reshape(-1,7,7)
x.shape
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([16,7,7])
```